# Decrypt hashed password

Tags: encryption, hash, hashcode

For a lecture I have to decrypt a hash...but in the exercise no hint was given at all.

The only information that was supplied is this:

```
user;pass
leroy;06e2b745f3124f7d670f78eabaa94809
```

I should decrypt the passphrase and describe how such a task is done but unfortunately I have no idea how to approach this problem.

My first ideas where that it is "leroy" or "jenkins" (or something like "jenkinS") in md5 or something so I simply tried to guess the passphrase but I had no luck.

Could you give me a hint on how to approch such a problem?

Comment: You can't decrypt a hash code, hashing is not encryption. What was the exact task of the exercise?

Comment: "There are ways to determine a hashed phrase. Try this at the following example and describe what you have done."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an MD5 hash, look into rainbow tables and searching online will easily get you the original value of that hash.

Comment: Keep in mind the key difference between hashing and encrypting. A hash is not reversible, technically. Encryption is meant to be reversed, but protected, via a key. The type of hash that was provided in your lecture is infamous for being able to be reversed by iterating through millions of possible values and storing their hashed value in a table (rainbow table). You can thus look it up in reverse - by the hashed value - and get to the original value with minimal effort, if you have a precomputed rainbow table.

Comment: I just guessed that it might be a MD5 hash...how does one identify this properly?

Comment: If you want the answer, via a rainbow table lookup site, this will take you there: http://www.md5-hash.com/md5-hashing-decrypt/06e2b745f3124f7d670f78eabaa94809. If you want to continue to look on your own, feel free to avoid the link.

Comment: You can tell that it is MD5 because it is 32 characters and is hex characters, that's usually a tell tale sign.

Comment: thanks! :) Do you have an easy (beginner friendly) source on how rainbow tables work?

Comment: I didn't find any stellar resources, this is one of the better posts to be able to parse as a beginner: http://blog.codinghorror.com/rainbow-hash-cracking/. Please make sure to continue on to reading about salts (which help protect against rainbow tables), you may be a step ahead of the next lecture by doing so: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112002-1.aspx.